# Doubt in Conserving Linear Momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I have the following question. I'm not sure if the way the authors have applied Conservation of Linear Momentum is correct. I would like to get some opinion on this.

> Two Trucks each of mass $M$ are moving without friction in opposite direction on adjacent parallel tracks with same speed $u$. One is carrying potatoes and other is carrying onions, a bag of potatoes has a mass $m_1$ and a bag of onions has a mass $m_2$ (included in the mass of the truck $M$). When trucks get close to each other while passing, the drivers exchange a bag with the other one by throwing the other one. Find the final velocities of the trucks after exchange of the bags.

---

**My Attempt**:

For first truck $M\overline{u}=(M-m_1+m_2)\overline{v_1}$ and for second $M\overline{u}=(M-m_2+m_1)\overline{v_2}$ with $\hat{v_1}=-\hat{v_2}$.

But in the book it is claimed that $(M-m_1+m_2)v_1=(M-m_1-m_2)u$ and $(M-m_2+m_1)v_2=(M-m_1-m_2)u$.

Kindly tell which method is correct and why?

Comment: Note that the question would be more clear if it stated that the drivers threw their bags sideways (e.g., at right angles to their truck's direction of motion) as they passed each other.

Comment: Your equations assume that each truck has the same momentum before and after the exchange, and that the final speeds are equal.  The first assumption is not correct.  The second is doubtful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbook is correct, you should consider that the onion bag and the potato bag have momentum because they are in a moving system when thrown.

So we have for one truck $$Mu- m_1 u +m_2(-u)=(M-m_1+m_2)v_1$$

This is just linear momentum conservation since the truck throws a bag with mass $m_1$ and velocity $u$ and receives a bag with mass $m_2$ and velocity $-u$. The right side of the equation is the final momentum of the truck as you correctly wrote in your approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not correct.

Why should $v_1 = v_2$? They have different masses. They have been slowed down by different masses.

Answer (score 0):

The book is correct, you cannot apply COM to individual trucks as the onion and potato bags would exert forces on them(trucks). You have to apply COM considering truck+onion bag or truck+potato bag as a system which is what the book has done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the bags are thrown sideways and simultaneously, then momentum is conserved in the collision between truck1 and m2 (which occurs after m1 is thrown):  (M – m1) u – m2 u = (M – m1 + m2) v1 .  Similarly for Truck2:  -(M - m2) u + m1 u  =  (M -m2 + m1) v2 .  (Assuming u positive for truck1)  The book is correct.